# how to fix org.eclipse.jetty error in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

I'm trying to start someof another project on my Eclipse.

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.extensions.Frame;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.ClientUpgradeRequest;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
```

When I use codes " org.eclipse.jetty ", I have an error;
The import org.eclipse.jetty cannot be resolved.

How to I fix this problem? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Are you use maven or put jar files in the class path?

Comment: Sorry, can say I'm new on java but I search your comment on google it didn't help.Guess I don't use maven or put jar files in the class path.Thanks